# Proof of closedness in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I want to show that the following subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is closed:
$U=\{(x,y):y\ge \frac{1}{x^2+1}\}$

Strategies that I think might work:

1. Complement of a closed set is open.
2. For a continuous function, if the image is closed then the pre-image is closed. Though I don't know how this might help.
3. Boundary is contained in the set.

Though I don't know how to go about initiating the proof. Can someone provide me a starting idea?

Comment: I am a big fan of any argument in the style of (2).  Do you believe that the function $f(x,y) = y - \frac{1}{x^2+1}$ is continuous as a map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes! How should I proceed though

Comment: Isn't $y \geq \frac{1}{x^2+1}$ exactly the same statement as $y - \frac{1}{x^2+1} \geq 0$?

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks very much. Silly me.

Comment: If you iron it out, you should write it up and answer your own question.

Comment: Okay! I shall so that.

Answer (score 2):

To show that $U$ is closed, we consider the function $f(x,y)=y-\frac{1}{x^2+1}$. This is a continuous function of $x$ and $y$. Then for the closed set $S=\{z\in \mathbb{R}:z\ge 0\}$, we have that the pre-image should be closed. That is, $\{(x,y):y-\frac{1}{x^2+1}\ge 0\}$ is closed. This exaclty means that $U$ is closed.

Comment: Yes.  You should write $S=\{z \in \mathbb{R} : z \geq 0\}$ without mention of $f$.  Then, $U=f^{-1}(S)$.

Comment: I like this type of argument! I guess one minor comment is that you probably should add a (short) argument that the set $S$ is actually closed

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x_n,y_n)\in U$ and $x_n\to x$ and $y_n\to y$.  Show $(x,y)\in U$.